# How to pass parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass `id` parameter from `getCurrent` function to `tr`, `load` and `save` functions. But I do not know how to do that.

```
var Upda = function () {
    return {
        init: function (id, callback) {
            var getCurrent = KeyWord.getCurrentUser(
                function(data) {
                    var id = data.id;
                    console.log(id);
                }
            );
            var tr = KeyWord.byId(id,
                function (data) {
                    self._item = data;
                },
                function (error) { jqXhrErr(error); },
                function () { }
            );
            $.when(tr).done(function () {
                if ($.isFunction(callback)) callback();
            });
        },
        load: function (id) {
            var self = this;
            KeyWord.byId(id,
                function (data) {
                    self.formHandler.load(data);
                },
                function (error) { },
                function () { }
            );
        },
        save: function () {
            KeyWord.updateProfile(id,
                function (data) {
                   alert("data saved succesfully.");
                   location.reload();
                },
                function (error) {
                    jqXhrErr(error);
                },
                function () {
                    Metronic.unblockUI();
                }
            );
        },
    };
}();
```

Comment: function called `fn`, call it like `fn(parameter);` ... you pass it in when you call the function

Comment: how to apply function call in my scenario, and do I need to do like `save: getCurrent(function())` or how?